# Unix sort the key of the combination of alphanumeric character and ':', '/'

Tags: unix, sorting

I am trying sort the text file using the UNIX `sort` command (GNU 5.97 or 7.4) according to ASCII code. The lines in the file have a single column, which is used as the key in sort.

```
chr1:110170896:NM_004037:0:1:0/1
chr1:110170897:NM_004037:0:1:0/1
chr11:10325325:chr11:0:1:0/1
chr11::0325325:chr11:0:1:0/1
```

The ascii code of `:` is 58, and `1` is 49. However, when I sort the file with `sort -k 1,1 temp.txt`, the output is like this,

```
chr11::0325325:chr11:0:1:0/1
chr1:110170896:NM_004037:0:1:0/1
chr1:110170897:NM_004037:0:1:0/1
chr11:10325325:chr11:0:1:0/1
```

From the result, I have no idea how sort determines the order between `1` and `:`. If there were any fixed order, the first and the forth lines should be placed together.

Ideally, I hope to sort the key from the left character to the right character according to the ASCII code.

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
 sort -t : -k 1 filename
```

using the : as a field delimiter

Answer (score 3):

From the man page for GNU sort:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

Using `LC_ALL=C sort text` (where `text` is a file where I copied your sample data) on my machine gives the sort order you want.

Still no explanation for why chr11 doesn't sort together in the original example though...

Answer (score 2):

`sort` is locale sensitive. It will be affected by your locale setting.

You should try set the language to `C` to return to ASCII order.

Say run it as `LANG=C sort -k 1,1 temp.txt` or set your environment variable

If you need an explanation of the mis-order, it would be better to give your locale / LANG environment to dig out the reason.